# How to create a separate thread for serial port just for send running in background

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, serial-port

I have a c# WinForms program (vs2017) which part of it's  function communicates via RS232 with a counting scale.(updating display, and generating box labels)

I would appreciate help with creating  a separate  thread for writing to the port vs reading from port.(which is always listening)

the way the scale works is to send  it  "P\n\r"  (request for data)

it the returns whatever data is current (I.E. avg piece wait, tare , net wt, count qty  etc...)

the issue is if the scale didn't settle ,it will beep and send nothing , requiring a resend.

without the program knowing that data is not being sent.. this will end up with no additional read request and leave the app with no data,

I therefore cannot rely on returned data to know when to resend the read request to scale.

as a result what (I think) id needed is  to  setup a separate thread (running in the background) which will loop sending  the request at 1 second intervals. (it's to be on it's own thread so it won't interfere with flow of rest of program)

anyone who can chime in.. it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with your code and that creating a new thread is probably going to add to the issue rather than solve it. Also, creating a thread is trivial, so if you're not sure how to do that then it's likely that you have some issues with your code. Can you please post your code in the question? Then we can recommend the best way forward.

Comment: I've used the background worker class in WinForms before. Works really well with sync stuff. Not sure how it will handle async stuff.

Comment: @GHDevOps - You'd think seeing the code would be the best way to help the OP, right?

Comment: @Enigmativity He's new. We were all there at one point in time!